# reading all points with fread()

Tags: c

In my program I want to read 5 points with each fread() operation.
The output function has to read all points.
I understand what I have to do to read 5 points with my ouput function.

```
while(fread(&point, sizeof(point), 1, save) != 0){
        if(i == 5){
             break;
             }
        printf("x-value: %f",point.x);
        printf("\y-value: %f",point.y);          
        printf("\z-value: %f",point.z);
        printf("\n\n");
        i++;
}
```

But how can I read all points with my output function(with each fread() operation I have to read 5 points)?
How would this look like? I haven`t found an example in my books.

Comment: Why `if (i == 5) break;`? when you can `for (i = 0 ; ((i < 5) && (fread(&point, sizeof(point), 1, save) != 0)) ; i++)`?

Comment: What the issue with the code you show? Does it work?

Comment: the code works without a problem. But i can only read 5 points.

Comment: Posting the definition/assignment of `point` would be useful (singe, array or pointer?)

Comment: @chux It`s a struct like in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *how to store the `5` points*?, this might be what you are looking for

```
struct Point 
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct Point points[5];
size_t       i;
size_t       count;

count = fread(&points[0], sizeof(points[0]), 1, save);
for (i = 1 ; ((i < 5) && (count == 1)) ; i++)
    count = fread(&points[i], sizeof(points[0]), 1, save);
```

above it was assumed that `save` is a valid `FILE *` instance.

If you need to read all the points in a single `fread` call you can do it this way

```
count = fread(points, sizeof(points[0]), 5, save);
for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%f, %f, %f\n", points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
```

this program will ouput the `5` points.

Comment: thanks for the answer, fread() has to look like this in my exercise:  fread(&point, sizeof(point), 5, save)

Comment: @schaeffer.heng You mean you don't have to use the loop?

Comment: No, fread() just has to look like this:                                                 fread(&point, sizeof(point), 5, save), thats the only requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can practise with the other exercises.